# How do I scrape constantly updated JavaScript post-login using Python?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I know there are many similar questions, however, they are all piecemeal to the problem I have, and I haven't been successful in putting the information together.

I am using a FLIR ax8 thermal camera, and this camera has a web-interface that one can interact with via ethernet. Long story short, temperature values are constantly displayed and updated, and I would like to scrape those values. I would like to do this without opening a browser with a GUI, and just be able to call every so often to get them.

The first step is a simple login page, located at "cameraIP"/login. It's very basic, but I need a solution that gets me through this, and be able to maintain the login session. Then it's just the interface. Attached are two images, the first showing interface as seen in Chrome, and the second a terminal output of what I scraped using Python's Requests module.

As you can see, the numbers are clearly not there, as they are rendered by JavaScript. This is essentially all I have to work with. If someone could give advice on how this is possible to get those temperature values every so often, that would be great.

If there are ANY questions, just leave a comment down below and I can provide more information, such as the JS files listed under the web interface if they are needed.

[image: Chrome Inspect Element View]

[image: Scraped HTML with Requests]

Answer (score 0):

I personally use scrapy splash to render the javascript when scraping using scrapy: http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Could you link to me where that functionality is described?